# Condition for lvalues and rvalues in C

Tags: c

Here are the few definitions I read about lvalues

1. Expressions which can be used with & operator.  i.e if &(expression) is not an error, then the expression is an lvalue
2. Expression which results in objects that are not temporary
3. lvalue expressions can be used on both RHS and LHS of = operator
4. rvalue expressions can be used only on RHS

Please correct if wrong

Here's the question

I read ++x is a lvalue and x++ is an rvalue

```
int i = 0;
printf("%p",(void*)&++i);
```

If so, why is this an error?

If lvalue expressions can be used on lhs

```
int i = 0;
++i = 10;
```

Why can't I use the above statement??Both the above are resulting in errors

**Update: Both the above statements are fine in C++**

Comment: ++i operator does "return" a value, but not the variable itself. hence it's address can not be retrieved.

Comment: `++x` is not an lvalue in C.

Comment: Where did you read that "++x is a lvalue and x++ is an rvalue"?

Comment: @PascalCuoq Oh my god..They are lvalues in C++, All the above statements are giving out correct answers in C++. This is weird

Comment: @Dariusz Why isn't your reasoning true for C++. It is returning an Address if I'm using C++

Comment: @tez the tag is `c`. C++ is an entirely different beast with operator overloading and all:)

Comment: An lvalue is a place to put a value, and an rvalue is either a pure calculated value or a place from which you can pull a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`++i` is an `lvalue` only in **C++**, in **C** it's an `rvalue` (called *value of an expression* in the C standard) which cannot be assigned.

Comment: Although strictly speaking, there is nothing in the C language called rvalue.

Comment: @Lundin It's indeed not used in the Standard, but it's still present in the index (pointing to *6.3.2.1*) and in the definition of *lvalue* « What is sometimes called *rvalue* is in this International Standard described as the *value of an expression* »

Comment: That's a foot note; foot notes are not normative text in ISO standards.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not arguing, I was just pointing out that the vague `rvalue` term has not been completely removed from the standard paper.

Answer (score 4):

Neither `++i` nor `i++` are lvalues.

You might be thinking about `*x++` and `*++x` which are both lvalues (if x has a pointer type).

Answer (score 2):

I thought that this question would be closed, and I only left a comment. What a big mistake;)

In C (the question's tag is *C*) ++i operator does "return" a value, but not the variable itself. Hence it's address can not be retrieved. In other words `++i` is not an lvalue. Neither is `i++`.

C++ is may be different from C in regard of certain constructs being l- and r-values.

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/

For C++ these two are lvalues.

This simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i=0;
  ++i = 10;
  printf("\n%d\n", i);
  ++i = ++i;
  printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Compiled with gcc will give:

```
lvalue.c:3: error: invalid lvalue in assignment
lvalue.c:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
lvalue.c:5: error: invalid lvalue in assignment
```

and for g++ compiles correctly and yelds:

```
10
12
```

Comment: I believe you meant something else here "In other words ++i is not an lvalue. Neither is ++i."

Answer (score 1):

The (rather vague) formal definition from C11:

(emphasis in **bold** font was added by me)

> 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators
>
> **An lvalue is an expression** (with an object type other than void) **that potentially designates an object** (64); if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the behavior is undefined. When an object is said to have a particular type, the type is  specified by the lvalue used to designate the object. A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-qualified  type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including, recursively,  any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-qualified type.

Foot note (not normative) with further explanation:

> 64) The name "lvalue" comes originally from the assignment expression E1 = E2, in which the left operand E1 is required to be a (modifiable) lvalue. It is perhaps better considered as representing an object "locator value". What is sometimes called "rvalue" is in this International Standard described as the "value of an expression".

So an lvalue must be something that "potentially" designates an object. Whatever "potentially" means is open for personal interpretation...

Despite the above foot note, the C standard lacks a formal definition of a rvalue. Ironically, the only place in the whole standard mentioning rvalue is that one foot note.

In your case, neither ++i nor i++ designates an actual object, so neither of them are lvalues. They are rather rvalues.

Comment: Though since the C standard is fuzzy, feel free to call anything rvalue. You could state that your dog is a rvalue and nobody could prove you wrong.

Comment: Regarding the "potentially", think of `*ptr`. For example when `ptr` points one element after the last in an array, `*ptr` does not designate an object. But `*ptr` _potentially_ designates an object, and is an lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

By making `++i` an lvalue, imagine that you can now do:

```
int i=2;
++i = ++i;
```

Apart from nasal daemons, what would you like `i` to look like afterwards? 4? 3?

Comment: The behavior would only be as undefined as `i = i++`.

Comment: @zakinster `i = i++` is only undefined because it modifies the same variable twice without a sequence point in between. `++i = ++i` is undefined for the same reason, but it is also undefined because `++i` is not a lvalue. So it is _more_ undefined! :)

Comment: And this doesn't answer the question, it is merely a comment.

Comment: @Lundin The comment (as the answer) was under the assumption "if `++i` were an *lvalue*". I was just pointing out that the undefined behavior would be only due to the lack of sequence point. Although, if `++i` is not an `lvalue`, this wouldn't be undefined since this wouldn't even compile.