# Error in post incement of a preincremented variable (++i)++?

Tags: c

In the following code segment, I was expecting the answer to be 5 but it shows compile time error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 4;
    printf("%d", (++i)++);
    return 0;
}
```

What is the reason?. Here `++i` returns an l value right So we could increment it right?

Comment: Even if it were syntactically correct, it would be undefined behavior, so you could not expect 5.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but the answers there are better answers to the question here than the answers here.

Comment: @PascalCuoq It was int i=4 (edited)

Comment: @PascalCuoq No not duplicate with that link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`postincrement\decrement` or `preincrement\decrement` requires `lvalue` and returns `rvalue`. that's why you are getting an error.

```
++i =>returns rvalue

(rvalue)++ => error
```

In c++ the situation is different because of `reference` types.In c we don't have any `reference` type.

```
in c++

++i => returns reference to i that is lvalue.

lvalue++ => Way to go!
```

[Demo for c++](http://ideone.com/fKEfyq)

even it is working, It is a `undefined behavior`. You should not modify the same variable more than once in a same statement.

Comment: It's not UB. It doesn't even compile.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yeah! corrected.

Comment: this is the same in C++ also right ?

Comment: @san45 **NO!** refrence is magic.

Comment: You know what's magic? Undefined behavior. I think this should be mentioned instead of giving the impression that `(++i)++` is correct in C++.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Oh! yes. you are right. It was my first line when i answered it but then removed it because of C tag. And later while editing i forgot to mention it. :P. Copied from the draft.

Comment: I think your statement, *"You can not modify the same variable more than one time in a same statement."* is misleading.... you ***can*** do it, it is allowed.  You just cannot predict the results.

Answer (score 5):

(++i) returns an rvalue. This cannot be incremented.

Comment: is ++i returns lvalue?

Comment: @san45 Did you bother reading this one-liner? "(++i) returns an rvalue" -- so then does it return an lvalue? **No it doesn't. Period.**

Comment: had a comment below saying that ++i returns lvalve that why

Comment: @san45 ++i operator returns a "value", but not the variable itself. So it's address can not be retrieved, which disregards it as an lvalue.

Comment: Some useful links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399485/condition-for-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c , http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/